# How to fix key mapping for control key

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, bashrc

As I have mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099022/keyboard-shortcuts-including-the-control-key-returns-caret-plus-the-capita) for some reason whenever I try to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key for any of the keyboard shortcuts, it prints the caret sign `^`. Here is my `.bashrc` file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi


# export TERM=”screen-256color” 


if [ -f `which powerline-daemon` ]; then
  powerline-daemon -q
  POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
  POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
  . /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

And when I run `stty -a` I get:

> speed 9600 baud; rows 55; columns 204; line = 0; intr = ^C; quit = ^\;
>   erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch =
>   ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
>   lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
>   -parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
>   -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8 opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr
>   -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
>   echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

I need to diagnose why this has happened and how I can resolve it.

Comment: Make a copy of your .bashrc and eliminate lines until it works as expected. Which line is responsible for this change in the behaviour?

Comment: ok, that would be a bit cumbersome. I was hoping I could receive a more straightforward approach.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Does it all work correctly if you remove your `bashrc` entirely?  If so, then the problem is `bashrc` *or one of the files it sources*.  Nobody else can see what's in those files, and repeated rounds of "delete half and try again" is not that cumbersome for a file that size.

Comment: You failed to say that this problem appear when you ssh from a Mac to a Ubuntu system. Have you tried a reboot (of both computers) already ?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I renamed the `.bashrc` and rebooted the server, the issue still persists! there must be other files loading at startup too?

Comment: @Foad For **Both** computers?. That seems odd. That a ctrl-c prints a ^C is not so odd, it is a very old way to encode control characters by shifting the seventh bit. So ctrl-a (001) is ^A, ctrl-b (002) is ^B, etc. Is a ctrl-c still working? To test: execute `sleep 20` and press Ctrl-C to find out if it stops. If it does, the chracters are working, if not, the console is not receiving the characters (I suspect it is).

Comment: Then, if the console receives the characters, what do you see if you execute `cat -A` and type some control characters like `Ctrl-A`, `Ctl-b`, `Alt-tab`, the arrows, etc. If the X server is correctly capturing the shortcuts, the `Alt-tab` should not be received by your console application, if it is, there is a problem with `X` shortcuts. Please test and report back. @Foad

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the following:

```
xmodmap -pke
```

Like on my system the control keys are:

- This will list the current mapping of your keys. If you find the offending setting you can reassign that key.

  ```
  keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
  keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
  ```

Use xev to find out what the keystream is, then remap it back to control.

- My xev shows this for control:

  ```
  KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
  root 0x15c, subw 0x0, time 5417642, (167,-18), root:(195,67),
  state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
  XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
  XFilterEvent returns: False
  ```

Something like:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R"
```

Would make my control key function normally.

To make this permanent edit your xorg configuration file to reflect the new mapping.